# PHP Пример  наследования

Tags: ооп, шаблоны, php, mvc, наследование

Есть родительский класс:

```
class Indexcontent {
var $indexcontenttpl;
var $filename;

function Gethtml($filename) {
    $indexcontenttpl = filegetcontents($filename);
    echo $indexcontenttpl;
    }
function Getfilename($filename) {
    $indexcontent_tpl = filegetcontents($filename);
        }
}
```

Вызов его работает:

```
 $index_file = new Indexcontent;

$indexfile->Get_html("tpl/header.tpl");
```

Создал дочерний класс:

```
class Fotopreview extends Indexcontent {

    var $previewdescription;
    var $filetpl;
function Replasedata($previewdescription,  $filetpl) {

    $filetpl = strreplace("{previewdescription}", $previewdescription, $filetpl);
    echo $filetpl;
    } 
}
```

Что я делаю не так, вызывая дочерний класс?
Мой способ (не рабочий):

```
$fotopreview = new Fotopreview; 
$filetpl = $fotopreview->Getfilename("tpl/fotopreview.tpl");
$fotopreview->Replasedata($row['previewdescription'],$filetpl );
```

Данные до дочерней функции доходят (проверял), но на выходе ноль. Файл .tpl существует, и там есть `{previewdescription}`.

P.S. Убрал нижние подчеркивания из названий функций, классов и переменных - потому как разметка пытается распознать курсив.

Comment: > P.S. Убрал нижние подчеркивания из названий функций, классов и переменных - потому как разметка пытается распознать курсив.

Если правильно использовать разметку, то проблем с курсивами не будет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Много ошибок:

1. Прекратите писать var в объявлении свойств класса (на дворе 2014, на данный момент последняя версия PHP 5.6.3, на хостингах 5.4.x). Доп.инфо. (Инкапсуляция - видимость объектов. public - можно обращаться к объекту из любого места кода (по умолчанию все объекты объявляются с этим свойством). private можно обращаться только внутри класса. protected - можно обращаться внутри класса и в дочерних классах.)
2. Метод `Getfilename` должен возвращать имя файла, судя из его названия, а он занимается ерундой.
3. Вы в принципе должны определиться, чем занимается ваш класс и какое у него API.
4. Не дублируйте функционал методов.
5. Не пишите лишнего, если не собираетесь использовать, - это лишний мусор.
6. Используйте переводчик, если не знаете, как правильно пишется на английском то или иное слово (не Foto, а Photo).
7. Методы с общими названиями (`replaceData`) не должны быть привязаны к частным вещам (`{previewdescription}`), для его пишите частные методы (`replaceDataPreviewDescription`).

Получаем на выходе:

```
// Существует правила оформления кода, например, название классов пишутся с большой буквы
class ContentTemplate
{
    // тут будем хранить имя файла и по запросу его использовать
    private $filename;
    // тут будем хранить содержание файла и по запросу его использовать
    private $content;

    // а название методов с маленькой
    public function setFilename($filename) {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        return $this;
    }

    // Возвращаем содежимое файла (читаем из файла один раз, если он не пуст)
    public function getContent() {
        // мы кешируем содержание файла, для того, что бы не читать его с из файла
        // (это долго, ресурсозатратно, и нагрузка на жесткий диск)
        if (empty($this->content)) {
            $this->content = file_get_contents($this->filename);
        }
        echo $this->content;
    }

    // выносим сюда, чтобы следующий дочерний класс это смог использовать
    public function replaceData($key, $value) {
        return str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->getContent());
    }
}

$ct = new ContentTemplate;
$content = $ct->setFilename('tpl/header.tpl')->getContent();
var_dump(content);

class PhotoPreview extends ContentTemplate
{
    public function replaceDataPreviewDescription($value)
    {
        return $this->replaceData('previewdescription', $value);
    }
}

$fp = new PhotoPreview;
$content = $fp->setFilename('tpl/fotopreview.tpl')
           ->replaceDataPreviewDescription($row['previewdescription']);
var_dump(content);
```

Надеюсь, я правильно уловил вашу мысль. В идеале в коде не хватает обработчиков ошибок, но тут уже сами.

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filetpl = $fotopreview->Getfilename("tpl/fotopreview.tpl");
```

ваша функция ничего не возвращает.

```
function Getfilename($filename) {
    $indexcontent_tpl = filegetcontents($filename);
    }
```

`return`  где?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $indexcontenttpl; // var в PHP не нужен, а вот доступ надо бы прописать
function Gethtml($filename) {
  $this->indexcontenttpl = filegetcontents($filename); //используйте $this->, раз уж он определяется в классе
}
//коль мне не изменяет память, надо бы скобочки при инициализации класса:
$fotopreview = new Fotopreview();
//str_replace() - прочтите внимательно еще раз, пожалуйста
//на вход подаются либо строки, либо массивы (причем второй может быть меньше первого
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

P.S. Как верно подметил [[@Ale_x](/users/3785/ale_x)](/users/3785/ale_x), у Вас нет ни одного return (виноват, пропустил).

Comment: > коль мне не изменяет память, надо бы скобочки при инициализации класса
не обязательны

Comment: :-) Возможно. Но привычка дело упрямое. К тому же это было так - к слову.